# How to delete from dcm4chee-arc server

Tags: mysql, ldap, apache-ds

How to delete studies, files and all or some records from dcm4chee-arc server or possibly clean in like fresh new? I've installed version 5 following this [instructions](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-arc-light/wiki/Installation). I've used Apache DS as the LDAP server and using mysql as database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UI, there are three, vertical dots. Press that and more actions are available at the study, series, and instance level. The trashcan should reject the instances (i.e. move them to the trash). If you search the trash AE, the trashcan icon is replaced with an X that says "Delete Permanently"